# Xamarin iOS: How can I open a pdf file using a standard reader

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to open a pdf file using a default reader, android works, but for iOS i can not. And I do not have a solid experience with C # only 2 months

```
 public void SaveOpen(string filename, MemoryStream stream)
        {

            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path, filename);

            //Create a file and write the stream into it.
            FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();


            UIViewController currentController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
            while (currentController.PresentedViewController != null)
                currentController = currentController.PresentedViewController;
            UIView currentView = currentController.View;

        }
```

Comment: Can't you load it on a webview? Must be a default app?

Comment: Yes, should be @BrunoCaceiro

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro já vi que és Portugues e acho que podemos falar portugues. Sim eu preciso abrir com um leitor padrão, e no android eu consigo baixar um arquivo pdf e abrir logo e já no iOS nao abri.

Comment: We need to speak in english. What error are you getting?

Comment: I can not see the pdf, it does not show any errors @Bruno

Comment: @ManOfWar can you help

Comment: But you want to load a file remotely, or local?

Answer (score 0):

To open a pdf file from a filePath:

```
  public void OpenPDF(string filePath)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

        QLPreviewController previewController = new QLPreviewController();
        previewController.DataSource = new PreviewControllerDataSource(fi.FullName, fi.Name);

        UINavigationController controller = FindNavigationController();
        if (controller != null)
            controller.PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);
    }


    private UINavigationController FindNavigationController()
    {
        foreach (var window in UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows)
        {
            if (window.RootViewController.NavigationController != null)
            {
                return window.RootViewController.NavigationController;
            }

            var value = CheckSubs(window.RootViewController.ChildViewControllers);
            if (value != null)
                return value;
        }

        return null;
    }


    private UINavigationController CheckSubs(UIViewController[] controllers)
    {
        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            if (controller.NavigationController != null)
            {
                return controller.NavigationController;
            }

            var value = CheckSubs(controller.ChildViewControllers);

            return value;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

So, in your code, after saving it, just call OpenPDF with the correct path.